# How to efficiently convert minutes to "hours:minutes"

Tags: ruby

For a tutorial I need to write a method that will take in a number of minutes, and return a string that formats the number into "hours:minutes".

My answer was:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hrs = 0
  min = 0
  if minutes >= 60
    min = minutes % 60
    hrs = (minutes - min) / 60
    min = format('%02d',min)
  else
    min = minutes
  end
  return "#{hrs}:#{min}"
end
```

The tutorial answer is:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hours = 0

  while minutes >= 60
    hours += 1
    minutes -= 60
  end

  if minutes < 10
    minutes_s = "0" + minutes.to_s
  else
    minutes_s = minutes.to_s
  end

  return hours.to_s + ":" + minutes_s
end
```

They both seem to return the same thing. Is my answer OK, or is theirs a better solution?

Comment: Your question is asking for opinions which is actually off-topic on SO. Neither is a particularly good solution since they don't take advantage of the power of the language. Instead, @ChrisHeald's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/40774746/128421 is exactly what I'd have used. It's elegant and takes advantage of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is perfectly fine, if not a better more succinct way for making the method. Performance wise, your answer is only minimally better as you're using a modulos operation where they are using a while loop in their code. I believe the tutorial is answered the way it is, is so that beginners can better grasp control flow and loops. Lastly, you can leave out the 'return' on the second to last line as ruby will implicitly return the last thing it evaluates in a method. But that's more of a individual preference just incase you come across it.

Comment: so instead of : return "#{hrs}:#{min}", I would just use:"#{hrs}:#{min}"

Comment: @Jeremy Correct

Answer (score 5):

Your answer is OK, but you could have shortened it further.

You can remove the conditional from your code, the `if` part works just fine in either case:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hrs = 0
  min = 0
  min = minutes % 60
  hrs = (minutes - min) / 60
  min = format('%02d',min)
  return "#{hrs}:#{min}"
end
```

And you can remove the default values:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  min = minutes % 60
  hrs = (minutes - min) / 60
  min = format('%02d',min)
  return "#{hrs}:#{min}"
end
```

And because this is integer division, you can remove the subtraction:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  min = minutes % 60
  hrs = minutes / 60
  min = format('%02d',min)
  return "#{hrs}:#{min}"
end
```

And you can move the entire formatting into `format`:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  min = minutes % 60
  hrs = minutes / 60
  format('%d:%02d', hrs, min)
end
```

And you can use [`divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) instead of `%` and `/`:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hrs, min = minutes.divmod(60)
  format('%d:%02d', hrs, min)
end
```

And you can avoid the variables if you use a splat (`*`):

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  format('%d:%02d', *minutes.divmod(60))
end
```

And you can avoid the splat if you use [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-25) instead of `format` because it takes an array:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  '%d:%02d' % minutes.divmod(60)
end
```

Chris Heald already suggested this in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774582/how-to-efficiently-convert-minutes-to-hoursminutes#comment68773417_40774746), but I thought it might be helpful to show the refactoring steps.

Comment: I like the format of your answer (as well as the content). Can you set it to music?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer your answer (as a Rubyist) to that of the accepted one. You could minify some things, but it reads cleaner than their solution as is. Avoid using the `return` keyword unless you absolutely need to: Ruby automatically returns the last evaluated statement in a method. Any answer you will get here is going to be subjective to some degree.

The best way to answer the question of "is this idiomatic" when alone is to consult the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). I understand the desire to learn idioms while learning a programming language, but keep in mind: you need to form those habits for whatever *your personal objective* dictates, within reasonable bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Here'a one way to do it in Ruby using [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod):

```
def hours_mins mins
  hours, minutes = mins.divmod 60
  if minutes < 10
    minutes = minutes.to_s.prepend '0'
  end
  "#{hours}:#{minutes}"
end

puts hours_mins   5 #=> 0:05
puts hours_mins 125 #=> 2:05
puts hours_mins 150 #=> 2:30
```

Comment: I'd just go with `"%d:%02d" % minutes.divmod(60)`

Comment: @ChrisHeald ooh that's pretty neat.

Comment: See [Kernel#format](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) for an explanation of the formatting codes @Chris used in his excellent suggestion. [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod) is a very handy method that's greatly underused. sagar, if you like the suggestion, you should edit your answer to incorporate it. After all, we want to present the best solution. If you want to attribute the change to Chris, I suggest you do that in a comment, to keep the answer "clean".

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the suggestion and especially the link to `Kernel#format`, I will have to get stuck in. Regarding `divmod`, I'm pretty sure (amongst many other things) I picked it up from you at some point!

Comment: You could also use [`rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-rjust) to pad with zeros, i.e. `minutes.to_s.rjust(2, '0')`